# Синхронизация вывода потоков POSIX

Tags: c++, c, многопоточность, pthread, posix

Нужно что бы два потока параллельно печатали на экран. (Первый поток печатает числа 1,2,3...10 Второй - 100,200,300...1000). Причём вывод должен быть синхронизирован: сначала родительский поток выводит первую строку, затем дочерний первую, затем родительский вторую строку, затем дочерний вторую и т.д.(100,1,200,2,300,3...) Использовать нужно мьютексы.

```
pthread_mutex_t mut;

void printt(int i){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
   cout<<i<<endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}

void* func(void*){
   for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        printt(i);
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   pthread_mutex_init(&mut,0);

   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid,0,func,0);

   for(int i=100;i<=1000;i+=100){
        printt(i);
   }
   pthread_join(tid,0);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);
   return 0;
}
```

Мой код же печатает сначала main поток 100,200... а потом 1,2... Хотя во время отладки программы печатает, как сказано в задании.

Comment: Такая постановка задачи превращает многопоточную программу в однопоточную по факту, там все будут ждать друг друга. А порядок распределения между тредами никак не гарантируется. Мутекс включит глобальные тормоза на все происходящие, и получиться медленнее чем в одном потоке + ресурсы на старт потока, минимум 4мб на поток оверхед.

Comment: На запуск потока нужно время. Поэтому второй (основной) поток успевает отработать до того, как запустится первый.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, проводите експеремент, запустите 10 потоков из цикла `for` например, в качестве аргумента передавайте итератор цикла, и посмотрите в каком порядке они будут выполняться. Если у вас очень быстрая машина запустите 20-30 :)

Comment: Если еще  интересно, то дополнил ответ немного измененным вашим кодом.

Comment: Автор, а вообще-то, о вот таких штучках в задаче №10 из серии ваших заданий `...11. Синхронизированный вывод 2

Докажите, что задача 10 не может быть решена с использованием двух мутексов без использования других средств синхронизации.

12. Синхронизированный вывод 3

Решите задачу 10 с использованием условной переменной и минимально необходимого количества мутексов.` было бы неплохо явно сообщать в тексте вопроса, а не весьма смутно в комментариях. (то-то я смотрю без циклического опроса или `pthread_cond/pthread_signal` решение не складывается...)

Answer (score 2):

**Предупреждение:** согласно POSIX данное решение даёт UB [<sup>[1]</sup>](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html), хотя и, судя по всему, он работает в реализации pthreads от glibc/linux; он приведен лишь для справки/как идея и не должен использоваться. Спасибо *@VTT* за замечание.

---

Для решения задачи нужно количество мьютексов равное количеству потоков.

Идея в том, чтобы мьютексы захватывались разными потоками попеременно, т.е. входя в критические секции нужно захватывать свой мьютекс, а при выходе отпускать мьютекс следующего потока. Само собой, перед началом выполнения свободным должен быть отпущен только один мьютекс. В итоге получается нечто следующее:

```
pthread_mutex_t mut1;
pthread_mutex_t mut2;

void printt1(int i){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mut1);
   cout<<i<<endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut2);
}

void printt2(int i){
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mut2);
   cout<<i<<endl;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut1);
}

void* func(void*){
   for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        printt2(i);
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   pthread_mutex_init(&mut1,0);
   pthread_mutex_init(&mut2,0);
   pthread_mutex_lock(&mut2);

   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid,0,func,0);

   for(int i=100;i<=1000;i+=100){
        printt1(i);
   }

   pthread_join(tid,0);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut1);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "нужно захватывать свой мьютекс, а при выходе отпускать мьютекс следующего потока"  - так делать нельзя, это приводит к неопределенному поведению. `pthread_mutex_unlock` можно вызывать, только если мьютекс был успешно захвачен этим же потоком.

Comment: @VTT, можно пруф? в `man`'е этого не вижу...

Comment: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_lock.html - *"If a thread attempts to unlock a mutex that it has not locked ..., pthread_mutex_unlock() shall behave as described in the Unlock When Not Owner column of the following table."* - ну и в таблице для всех вариантов это либо UB, либо ошибка

Comment: @VTT, спасибо, похоже не правду... через пару дней поправлю/перепишу ответ...

Answer (score 1):

Функция `printt` печатает локальную переменную `i`, к которой у других потоков нет доступа, а синхронизация не ожидает завершения записи предыдущей строки другим потоком. Также полностью отсутствует обработка ошибок.

Comment: "Функция printt печатает локальную переменную i, к которой у других потоков нет доступа" то есть эту переменную нужно передавать по ссылке или указателю?

Comment: "а синхронизация не ожидает завершения записи предыдущей строки другим потоком" почему не ожидает? там же замок мьютекс стоит. Пока один поток печатает другой не может

Comment: @zhukov "*Пока один поток печатает другой не может*" - да, но это не означает, что "*один поток начинает печатать после того как предыдущий напечатал стороку*"

Comment: да, но это не означает, что "один поток начинает печатать после того как предыдущий напечатал стороку" как это сделать?

Comment: @zhukov Подсказка: потоки должны как-то обмениться информацией о своем состоянии.

Comment: получилось решить при помощи обычного глобального булевого флага (вы это имели ввиду под обменом информацией или сигналы SIGINT и т.д.?) без мьютексов и при помощи холостых циклов. Но в задании сказано наоборот - c мьютексами и без холостых циклов. Кстати, я эту задачу не выдумал, она [вот здесь](http://parallels.nsu.ru/WackoWiki/KursOperacionnyeSistemy/PraktikumPosixThreads/PthreadTasks?v=1bu5) под номером 10. Может что-то ещё подскажите?

Comment: @zhukov Доступ к такому флагу из разных потоков без синхронизации является неопределенным поведением. Так что тут нужны мьютексы (либо атомарные операции).

Answer (score 0):

Без сигналов , чтоб другой поток проснулся неудобно, придумал только сон. Вроде бы пашет. Нужна переменная для знака кому какая очередь.

```
// g++ -pthread mutex-semaph.cpp
#include <unistd.h>
# include <pthread.h>
# include <iostream>
pthread_mutex_t mut;
int queue = 1 ; // или 2

void printt(int i, int q){
Again   :
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
        if(queue == q)   std::cout<<i<<std::endl;
        else    {
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
            sleep(1);
            goto    Again   ;   }
        queue = 3 - q ;
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
}

void* func(void*){
   for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
        printt(i,2);
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   pthread_mutex_init(&mut,0);

   pthread_t tid;
   pthread_create(&tid,0,func,0);

   for(int i=100;i<=1000;i+=100){
        printt(i,1);
   }
   pthread_join(tid,0);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте разделяемую `volatile` переменную и mutex. Присвойте переменной 1, что означает печать будет проводить первый поток. Запустите потоки.

В каждом потоке в цикле захватываете mutex и  читаете значение переменной.

Если значение переменной в первом потоке равно 1, то он печатает данные и присваивает переменной 2. Аналогично, второй поток производит печать если значение переменной равно 2, после чего устанавливает ее в 1.
(*Обратите внимание, чтение и модификация переменной защищены mutex-ом.*)

Затем поток в любом случае снимает блокировку и (для оптимизации эффективности) вызывает [pthread_yield](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_yield.3.html).

Конкретно в вашем случае с внешним циклом и анализом очередности печати внутри `printt()` (очевидно, с целью не вытаскивать работу с mutex на уровень управления циклом) в этой функции нужно дождаться, пока общая переменная не примет нужного значения.

Впрочем, хватит общих слов. Вот немного модифицированный ваш код из текста вопроса.

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat t-seq-pri.c
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#else
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <stdio.h>
#endif

#include <pthread.h>

pthread_mutex_t mut;
volatile int turn;

void printt(int i, int q){
  int pri = 0;
  do {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mut);
    if (turn == q) {

#ifdef __cplusplus      
      cout<<i<<endl;
#else
      printf("%d\n", i);
#endif

      turn = (q == 1 ? 2 : 1);
      pri = 1;
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mut);
    pthread_yield();
  } while (!pri);
}

void* func(void *p){
  for(int i=1;i<=10;i++){
    printt(i, 2);
   }
   return 0;
}

int main() {
   pthread_mutex_init(&mut,0);

   pthread_t tid;
   turn = 1;

   pthread_create(&tid,0,func,0);


   for(int i=100;i<=1000;i+=100){
     printt(i, 1);
   }
   pthread_join(tid,0);
   pthread_mutex_destroy(&mut);
   return 0;
}



avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ gcc t-seq-pri.c -pthread -Wall -O3 && ./a.out
100
1
200
2
300
3
400
4
500
5
600
6
700
7
800
8
900
9
1000
10
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```